# Await For Certain Message using .awaitMessages()

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This block of code listens for `member`'s first message to be `yes`. However if `member`'s first message isn't `yes` the collection stops collecting messages and ends. How can I have this block wait for `member` to say yes even if other messages before did not. I've tried using `collected.content` instead of `collected.first().content` However that doesn't seem to work.

```
const filter = m => m.author.id === member.id

message.channel.send(message).then(() => {

   message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 10, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })

    .then(collected => {

       if (collected.first().content == 'yes') return console.log('A yes was found')

    }).catch(error => {

       return console.log('A yes was not found')

    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `if` statement inside your `then` callback to these lines instead :

```
const yes = collected.find(c => c.content === 'yes');
if (yes) return console.log('A yes was found');
```

This will attempt to find a message which's content is 'yes' from your collection,

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Still the same behavior :(

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing your filter with this one :

```js
const filter = m => { return m.author.id === member.id && m.content === 'yes' };
```